# HTML Radio Button Name / ID's and what it returns?

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to find out what my form returns from the radio buttons?

I am trying to get it to return back one of two options in my form.

```
<fieldset id="questRewardType">
  <input id="questRewardType" type="radio" name="questRewardType" value="0" checked><font color="#FFFFFF"> Item</font>
  <br>
  <input id="questRewardType" type="radio" name="questRewardType" value="1"><font color="#FFFFFF"> Currency</font>
 </fieldset>
```

if I was to select the radio button Currency that should return back "Currency"? Am I correct in thinking this?

Answer (score 0):

The value for a radio button set is determined by the `value` attribute of the checked radio button.

The label (which should be marked up with [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) not `font`), is used to tell the user what the radio button means.

Comment: Okay, sorry thanks. I had it before where "value" was "Currency" and not 1. The font is there to make the text white and that's it.

So if I used label, would that return "Item=0"?

I'm asking because I seem to be getting back "0" if I selected "1"

Comment: @Moretti — Use CSS to make text white, it obsoleted `<font>` in 1996. A label won't affect the value of the control. If you select the second checkbox, the submitted value will be `1`. Are you perhaps using `document.getElementById`? That won't get the *checked* checkbox, it will get the one which has the specified ID (error recovery will get the first one with the ID because an ID **must be unique**. Use a [validator](https://validator.nu/).